# How to mount volumes with docker-compose in- and outside of a VSCode devcontainer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

### Scenario

The project I'm working on (a React app) uses `docker-compose` to setup it's backend, webserver and frontend. I'm working inside a [VSCode `devcontainer`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) (Node with Typescript).

The Docker in Docker environment I've setup seems to work fine and I'm able to start each of the Docker containers but I had to adapt the code in the following manner because otherwise Docker wasn't able to locate the specified volumes to mount.

### Setup

First I needed to set a [remote environment variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_adding-environment-variables) in my `devcontainer.json`:

```json
"remoteEnv": {
    // the original host directory which is needed for volume mount commands from inside the container (Docker in Docker)
    "LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER": "${localWorkspaceFolder}"
}
```

I'm then using this environment variable in the `docker-compose.yaml` like so:

```yaml
services: 

  webserver:
      build: 
          context: ./docker
          dockerfile: webserver/Dockerfile
      image: webserver
      container_name: webserver_nginx
      ports:
          - 8080:80
      volumes:
          -  ${LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/webserver:/etc/nginx/conf.d
          -  ${LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/build:/var/www/html
      restart: unless-stopped
      depends_on: 
        - backend

  backend:
      ...
```

### Problem

On my machine (and on the machine of my colleagues who also use VSCode) everything works fine. But I have some teams members which don't use VSCode. When I commit the adapted `docker-compose.yaml` file, their setup doesn't work anymore and vice-versa if they adapt the file again to their needs.

### Question

How can I ensure that Docker compose works in- and outside of VSCode's `devcontainers`?

### Possible solutions?

- **Would it be possible to set the environment variable to a default value?** Because in my case the actual value that should be set if the project is not opened inside a `devcontainer` is just a simple dot (`.`). Because when I run the command `echo ${LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER}` inside the integrated VSCode terminal, the correct path gets printed. So it seems that VSCode just sets normal environment variables?
- **(If the assumption from above is correct) wouldn't it be possible to write a simple Bash script `install.sh` that set's the correct path automatically?** This script should only be run once during the setup of the project. How could this file look like?

Comment: Why don't you specify './webserver' as volume ? That should work also inside your vscode...

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose allow default value for variables:

> ${VARIABLE:-default} evaluates to default if VARIABLE is unset or
> empty in the environment.

See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

For you case example, you can use:

> ${LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER:-.}

PS: I never used that personnaly